# Replace $z$ with interpolated function and plotting

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, list-manipulation, interpolation, broken-code

I start off with this equation $z(x,y) = sin(xy)$. I create an interpolation from $0 < x < 5$ and $0 < y < 5$.

I then use this interpolation on a simple function $w(x,y) = x + y + z(x,y)$

I then do a contour plot of $w(x,y)$. Everything worked fine up to contour plot, and I'm not sure why.

**Interpolating the data:**

```
w[x_,y_,z_] := x + y + z
data1 = Flatten[ Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, 0, 5, 1}, {y, 0, 5, 1}], 1] 
int = Interpolation[data1]
```

**Plotting to see if the interpolation works:**

```
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}]
```

[image]

**Replacing $z$ with $int(x,y)$ to get $z(x,y)$ and plotting $w(x,y)$**

```
z1[x_, y_] := z [x, y] /. int[x, y]
w1[x_, y_] := w[x, y, z] /. z1[x, y]
ContourPlot[w1, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}]
```

Comment: Do you want this 
`ContourPlot[w[x, y, int[x, y]], {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}]`

Comment: I want $w(x,y)$ with the replaced value of $z(x,y)$

Comment: @user44840 If Hubble07's solution is what you wanted I'd like to know what you were attempting with `/.`.  Not only does not not work (see my answer) but I can't figure out what you thought it would do.  Understanding replacement rules is fundamental to using *Mathematica* well so I would like to help you reach that understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but this works fine:

```
ContourPlot[w[x, y, z] /. z -> int[x, y], {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 8}]
```

Comment: That's perfect.

Comment: but this is exactly what i said in the comments to the OP

Comment: +1 But please see that you should't interpolate from `0` to `5` and then plot the interpolated function from `0` to `8`.

Comment: @eldo good point. I didn't notice this...

Answer (score 1):

Working backward:

1. You never gave `w1` any arguments within `ContourPlot` (to fill its parameters).
2. The output of `z1[x, y]` is not a replacement rule.
3. The output of `int[x, y]` is not a replacement rule.

If you give the exact series of replacement that you wish to implement I can help you accomplish it.